# Remove indentation after nest list

Tags: markdown, indentation

I want to remove the indentation of text after a nested list, for example, with the following markdown code,

```
1. item01
2. item02
paragraph01
      * subitem01
      * subitem02  
paragraph02
```

the result I am trying to get is the indentation before `paragraph02` should be same as indentation before `paragraph01`, just like what is showed above. However, the result I got is

```
1. item01
2. item02
paragraph01
    * subitem01
    * subitem02  
      paragraph02
```

i.e., the indentation before `paragraph02` is same as the `subitem02`. I tried to put two space after `subitem02`, but it does not solve the problem. Is there a solution for this or the markdown designed in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you nest any block level content inside a list, you need to format that content as you would outside of a list, except have it indented one level. So, the entire content of you second list item would be:

```
item02

paragraph01

* subitem01
* subitem02

paragraph02
```

Note that the paragraphs need to have blank lines wrapped around them. Also note that the list item bullets are not at a different indentation level from the paragraphs.

Now, to nest that in a list item, just insert a bullet at the beginning of the first line and indent the entire rest one level. Like this:

```
* item02

    paragraph01

    * subitem01
    * subitem02

    paragraph02
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. At the end of a nested list I have a heading specified with ##### and it doen't output as a heading but is displayed asis and with indentation of the preceding list.

Comment: @ktyagi do you have the header surrounded by blank lines?